# Adding image into submit_tag in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, helper

I have a submit_tag like this :

```
<%= submit_tag "Convoquer les joueurs sélectionnés", class: "btn btn-success margin" %>
```

I want to add an image next to the text in the submit tag; I tried :

```
<%= submit_tag image_tag('fleche_droite.svg', class: 'fleche_subscription_index') + "Convoquer les joueurs sélectionnés", class: "btn btn-success margin" %>
```

But it doesnt work, any ideas ?

Comment: `But it doesn't work` - so what happens?

Answer (score 1):

Try [image_submit_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-image_submit_tag).

```
image_submit_tag("fleche_droite.svg", class: 'btn btn-success margin', alt: 'Convoquer les joueurs sélectionnés')
# => <input alt="Convoquer les joueurs sélectionnés" class="btn btn-success margin" src="/assets/fleche_droite.svg" type="image" />
```

Or You can do it like this:

ERB:

```
<%= submit_tag "Convoquer les joueurs sélectionnés", class: "btn btn-success margin" %>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="submit"]
{
  background:url('fleche_droite.svg');
  // more style
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the content you want in some parentheses and call html_safe on it:

```
(image_tag('fleche_droite.svg', class: 'fleche_subscription_index') + "Convoquer les joueurs sélectionnés").html_safe
```

So your tag becomes:

```
<%= submit_tag (image_tag('fleche_droite.svg', class: 'fleche_subscription_index') + "Convoquer les joueurs sélectionnés").html_safe, class: "btn btn-success margin" %>
```

Comment: Ah, darn. You're gonna have to post a bit more detail about how it fails in order to get better help in that case! Or perhaps Sunda's solution works for you.

Comment: well with your method I get on screen a button with no style and "<img class=" in it followed by : Convoquer les joueurs sélectionnés" class="btn btn-success margin" /> (no button, not style just plain text)